# How to bind the value to dropdown on another event angular2

Tags: angular

I have a dropdown which binds data from database

```
<select (ngModelChange)="load($event)">
 <option *ngFor="let type of types" [ngValue]="type">{{type.Name}}</option>
</select>
```

On another button click (not the dropdown change event) I get the type.Id which should be bound to this select, show the selected name and hold it for further use.
How can I do that.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using two way binding with ngModel

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedElement">
 <option *ngFor="let type of types" [ngValue]="type.id">{{type.Name}}</option>
</select>
{{selectedElement |json}}
```

Onclick of the button you access the selected id using

```
this.selectedElement.id
```

Update 1 : 
If you are looking to change the selected value based on the service response, use the below code,

HTML
    
          {{type.Name}}

Component

```
types:any[]=[
                {id:1,Name:'abc'},
                {id:2,Name:'abdfsdgsc'}
    ];
  /*item to be preselected should be in the below object which 
  *is returned by the web  service
  */
  selectedElement:any= 2;
```

Updated **[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/7o1ETf0t6aJ216fEK96V?p=preview)**

Comment: I want to do the opposite. On button click, I want the dropdown to bind to the id which is returned from database

Comment: where does the data comes to the dropdown, then?

Comment: It comes from a separate query on ngOnInit. There is nothing selected initially. After another button click, I need to select the value which maps to the dropdown list values. I hope I am clear

Comment: I want to do something like this in angular: dropdown.SelectedValue = reader[0].ToString();(this is in C#)

Comment: did u see the demo which is in the answer?

Comment: Sorry to say, but there is nothing in the demo. It just shows a label Hello Angular2 in my browser. Wish I could share the screenshot.

Comment: sorry about the wrong link. Have a look at it I updated

Comment: This is not my req. I need to select the item in dropdown based on a value which I get from database.ex: if i get the value 2 from database, abdfsdgsc should get selected. If I get 1 -> abc should get selected in dropdown

Comment: you mean about the preselected one in the dropdown??

Comment: @Aravind can you please help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50059278/how-to-bind-api-response-json-to-drop-down-in-angular4

Comment: @Nikson there is answer already is that useful? or need more help?

Comment: @Aravind got the solution from SO user but facing an issue

Comment: @Aravind error [ts] Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'

Comment: can you create a stackblitz please! @Nikson

Comment: @Aravind can you do anything in it

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

Set the selected if it matches the number you receive:

```
<select >
  <option value="select" disabled>--Select--</option>
  <option *ngFor="let type of types" [selected]="type.id == id" [ngValue]="type">{{type.name}}</option>
</select>
```

And when you receive your number, you set that value to `id` (or whatever variable you want). Here's a

### **[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/BhwXTzQskbfKsfcHbbyI?p=preview)**