# How to bind API response (json) to drop-down in Angular4

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working in an angular4 application in this I need to bind a drop-down from API response data .

I don't know how to fetch the specific data for the particular section from API.

Here API contains Category ,Group and Sub-group data .Each Group has 2 sub-groups.

I have created a stackblitz file for this Please take a look

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-carousel-dynamic2-y6iknh?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Here I receiving the API response ,But don't know how to assign the values to the dropdown positions.

Can anyone guide me to solve this ..

Comment: Can you please tell me if it is a dropdown menu? Or is it a dropdown, as in "select"?

Comment: Actually it is option like dropdown without borders like in the dropdown .

Comment: @Nikson let's discuss here!

Comment: @Aravind got the solution here but When I apply the code in my project it shows error [ts] Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'

Comment: @Aravind https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-carousel-dynamic2-y2qnjy?file=app/app.component.html 

It is working in stackblitz but not in my project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind data with some variable by parsing it into `json()` , then you will be able to fetch and consume data into your view like this

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.CartdataService.get_New_Products().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.dropdownData = data.json();
                  console.log(data.json());
      });


<div class="col-sm-12" style="margin-top: 20px !important" *ngFor='let data of dropdownData; let i=index'>
    <div class="col-sm-12 opt1">
        <div class="row">
            <h5>
                <a class="col-sm-12 font-weight-normal">
          {{data?.CAMD_ENTITY_DESC}}
        </a> 
            </h5>
            <i class="fa fa-angle-down ind" data-toggle="collapse" [attr.href]="'#collapseExample' + data?.CAMD_ENTITY_DESC"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 collapse opt1" [id]="'collapseExample' + data?.CAMD_ENTITY_DESC"
  *ngFor='let group of data?.group; let j=index'>
        <div class="row">
            <h6>
                <p class="dropdown-item col-sm-10">{{group?.CAMD_PRGRP_DESC}} </p>
            </h6>
            <i class="fa fa-angle-down ind arrow" data-toggle="collapse" [attr.href]="'#innerCollapse' + group?.CAMD_PRGRP_DESC"></i>
        </div>
    <div class="collapse col-sm-12" [id]="'innerCollapse' + group?.CAMD_PRGRP_DESC">
        <div class="row" *ngFor='let subgroup of group?.subgroup; let i=index'>
            <h6>
                <a class="dropdown-item opt">{{subgroup?.CAMD_PRSGRP_DESC}}</a>
            </h6>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is working example for the same

- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-carousel-dynamic2-y2qnjy?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: I know how to fetch individual items from json but In this case I need to iterate through the json and generate the dropdown as in my stackblitz file

Comment: something like this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-carousel-dynamic2-basnhu I just added it for one level

Comment: @Nikson Please check the link from the data you are fetching

Comment: @PardeepJain receiving the data ,You can see in console under "Response"

Comment: @Nikson check the updated answer and link with full answer

Comment: @PardeepJain got this error [ts] Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'

Comment: @PardeepJain I got the above error when I apply your code in my component.ts

Comment: seems error is from somewhere else as code is working fine on stackblitz

Comment: @PardeepJain looking for your reply

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169937/discussion-between-pardeep-jain-and-nikson).